# background images reported 404

Tags: css, tomcat

[image]
[image]

Some background images didn't show. So I open the browser console, the unloaded pics are reported `404`. And then I check my css on the browser console. I find out the url of background images didn't change. But I did change them in css of web path. I also checked the css of `web_war_exploded` path, it is same as the css of web path. It only didn't changed on browser console.

PS: The original file name of image is src.
When I change `src` to `image`, background images are showing.

Comment: Are you running a local server or a remote server? Remember to upload your files if remote. If local try restarting the server and clearing browser cache (CTRL+SHIFT+'R')

Comment: a local server. it works thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing your browser cache - this will reload the css-files.